# Why is my bagOfWord naive bayes algorithm performing worse than wekas StringToWordVector?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to build a naive bayes based classifier for 1000 positive+negative labled IMDB reviews (txt_sentoken) and weka API for Java.

As I wasn't aware of `StringToWordVector`, which basically provides a BagOfWords model that reaches an 80% accuracy, so I did the vocabulary building and vector creation myself, with an accuracy of only 75% :(

Now I'm wondering why my solution is performing so much worse.

1) From my 2000 reviews, I build the BagOfWords:

```
Pipeline<String, Void> bagOfWordsChain = Pipeline
        .start(Preprocessing.luceneTokenizer)
        .append(Preprocessing.stopwordFilter)
        .append(Preprocessing.vocabularyBuilder);
```

vacabularyBuilder takes the whitespace tokenized reviews, puts each unigram into a hashMap and counts the occurrences. Only words with an absolute polarity of 0.25 or above (according to SentiWordNet) are taken:

```
public class VocabularyBuilder implements Pipe<List<String>, Void> {
    public Map<String, Integer> _vocab = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();

    @Override
    public Void process(List<String> input)
    {
        for(String token: input){
            double pol = SentiAnalysis.sentiWordNet.getWordPolarity(token);

            if(pol >= 0.25) {
                this._vocab.put(token, this._vocab.getOrDefault(token, 0) + 1);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public void sortAndLimit(int n){
        this._vocab = this._vocab.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .limit(n)
                .collect(
                        toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                                LinkedHashMap::new));
    }

}
```

The resulting hashmap is ordered (desc) and limited to the top ~1500 words. So I'm getting the following vector:

```
{bad=43245, best=41292, better=28551, wrong=11935, unfortunately=11842, worst=9548, i=7526, wonderful=6727, excellent=5704, scary=5395, all=4361, greatest=4216, hate=4154, like=3688, out=3635, boss=3627, disturbing=3193, inspired=3162, some=2983, poorly=2914, just=2903, creepy=2883, worthy=2883, superb=2883, disappointing=2728, loving=2666, plain=2542, fake=2480, engaging=2449, good=2409, nasty=2387, lucky=2387, cheesy=2294, other=1931, well=1906, very=1863, unfortunate=1860, dirty=1829, mom=1736, delightful=1736, embarrassing=1705, make=1641, outrageous=1581, off=1579, really=1557, gorgeous=1550, alas=1550, troubled=1519, little=1500, over=1446, never=1373, downright=1364, horribly=1364, supernatural=1333, infamous=1333, psychotic=1271, know=1213, doom=1178, great=1148, love=1112, go=1109, awesome=1085, pseudo=1054, still=1047, world=994, paranoid=992, bastard=992, hapless=992, nifty=961, menacing=961, miserable=961, phony=930, worried=899, unrealistic=899, going=887, masterful=868, respected=868, pity=837, admirable=837, ruthless=837, chilling=806, horrific=806, spite=806, right=798, find=782, understated=775, damage=775, bully=744, fright=682, paranoia=682, unsatisfying=682, kudos=651, notorious=651, overacting=651, interesting=638, unoriginal=620, nostalgic=620, must=615, wounded=589, abusive=589, atrocious=589, hard=587, times=568, trying=566, kind=559, complaining=558, trashy=558, hollywood=532, cracking=527, glowing=527, sure=523, together=522, black=521, heartbreaking=496, bonnie=496, letdown=496, regret=496, disastrous=496, faux=496, nerve=496, imitation=496, whole=494, sex=476, less=475, wondrous=465, whiny=465, groan=465, completely=440, wretched=434, sumptuous=434, punk=434, botched=434, smashing=434, small=429, dead=418, evil=417, humor=410, true=410, lost=409, salt=403, idyllic=403, schlock=403, healing=403, momma=403, second=400, problem=396, comic=389, alien=377, reverend=372, inviting=372, horrid=372, righteous=372, props=372, lucrative=372, impressively=372, soil=372, autistic=372, entrapment=372, certainly=361, face=357, despite=352, nice=344, perfect=343, gusto=341, crappy=341, messy=341, undeniable=341, shoddy=341, seeing=338, game=321, entertaining=314, dark=312, protecting=310, frivolous=310, troubling=310, dandy=310, fortunate=310, worrying=310, bush=310, unwilling=310, tingle=310, ashamed=310, short=309, beautiful=299, obvious=292, known=292, classic=289, fine=284, eyes=282, compassionate=279, amusingly=279, formidable=279, infatuated=279, topping=279, dreck=279, protected=279, underdog=279, woefully=279, howling=279, weep=279, question=277, truly=274, boring=270, killer=270, 1=269, fiction=257, yes=256, novel=255, possible=253, stupid=253, murder=250, demonic=248, infuriating=248, joking=248, bullshit=248, faint=248, extremely=248, fumbling=248, insomnia=248, respectability=248, levity=248, disconcerting=248, handicapped=248, wonder=247, sound=245, worse=245, taking=242, none=242, emotional=239, meet=236, elements=236, hell=234, interest=232, battle=229, obviously=228, enjoy=227, needs=221, poor=219, bogus=217, virtuoso=217, swell=217, bliss=217, droll=217, incredulous=217, redneck=217, scummy=217, otherworldly=217, amuse=217, bum=217, success=216, happy=215, important=215, giving=214, recent=211, basically=211, easily=209, apparently=209, cop=201, difficult=200, complete=197, due=196, gone=195, quality=195, dramatic=194, annoying=189, smart=189, dogged=186, crushing=186, finer=186, brag=186, upsetting=186, regrettably=186, nonexistent=186, fab=186, pleaser=186, delayed=186, tumultuous=186, enamored=186, idealized=186, botch=186, absolutely=186, imaginary=186, incongruity=186, sickly=186, mono=186, depraved=186, prejudice=186, successful=186, read=185, intelligent=184, clear=183, amazing=181, low=179, animated=179, villain=178, definitely=177, clever=177, add=177, giant=176, brilliant=176, solid=174, thinking=174, potential=171, unlike=167, perfectly=166, sweet=166, non=166, enjoyable=164, decent=164, cold=161, impossible=161, exciting=160, wanted=159, neither=158, trouble=157, otherwise=156, opulent=155, penniless=155, liked=155, esteemed=155, reprehensible=155, stink=155, congratulations=155, catastrophic=155, battered=155, sterling=155, majestic=155, mangled=155, researcher=155, wonderment=155, outraged=155, outdated=155, forged=155, thorough=155, hurting=155, dumb=155, crummy=155, filthy=155, talented=154, silly=152, truth=151, joke=150, totally=146, terrible=143, fear=142, entirely=142, ability=140, killing=138, cheap=137, background=137, lots=137, disaster=136, highly=136, amusing=135, master=135, beauty=135, further=134, cute=134, wish=134, awful=132, plenty=131, believable=130, charm=130, imagine=128, choice=128, tough=128, somewhere=127, famous=126, okay=125, resentful=124, perplexed=124, deplorable=124, hamming=124, incredibly=124, honored=124, melancholic=124, woeful=124, amiss=124, indignity=124, disabled=124, improving=124, disembodied=124, repugnant=124, cringing=124, workmanlike=124, maddening=124, stinky=124, opportunity=124, seemingly=124, fugly=124, enthralled=124, reputable=124, discernable=124, elegance=124, interested=123, alive=122, ready=120, average=119, apart=118, wasted=118, becoming=117, missing=116, bizarre=115, waiting=114, saving=112, adventure=111, lame=111, camp=109, sad=108, tried=107, gay=106, wise=106, charming=105, rescue=105, fair=105, decided=104, fox=104, sadly=103, horrible=103, winning=102, exception=102, older=102, accident=102, younger=102, bright=101, desperate=101, surprising=100, revenge=100, lose=100, opinion=100, weird=100, apparent=100, epic=99, nicely=98, nowhere=98, crazy=98, buy=98, loved=97, witty=97, please=97, pathetic=97, fantasy=96, kept=96, cameo=96, fascinating=96, spirit=95, superior=95, shame=94, confusing=94, confused=94, untamed=93, shapely=93, bias=93, masterpiece=93, intriguing=93, fiendish=93, superlative=93, jerking=93, indignant=93, mournful=93, despondent=93, troublesome=93, malice=93, sitting=93, speaking=93, sheltered=93, bollocks=93, alienating=93, wail=93, rowdy=93, meddling=93, generalized=93, motormouth=93, swoon=93, banner=93, moralizing=93, propelling=93, damaging=93, smelly=93, crap=93, overjoyed=93, interfering=93, mischief=93, mommy=93, disenchanted=93, crotchety=93, abhorrent=93, squalor=93, condemning=93, matt=92, necessary=92, magic=92, pointless=92, respect=92, pain=90, sub=90, moral=89, touching=89, rob=89, drawn=89, floor=88, color=88, keeping=88, ed=88, phantom=88, unfunny=88, damn=88, suspect=88, criminal=88, emotion=88, anti=87, blame=87, grand=86, ok=86, wonderfully=85, frightening=84, walking=84, utterly=84, attractive=83, rocky=83, honest=82, difference=82, feelings=82, trust=82, safe=82, dying=81, plus=81, dangerous=81, visually=81, shock=80, sexy=80, fail=80, humour=79, goofy=79, constant=79, hidden=78, welcome=78, content=77, fantastic=77, contrived=77, genius=77, sick=77, fit=76, badly=76, forgotten=75, won=75, excuse=75, guilty=75, instance=75, offensive=75, fault=75, super=74, outstanding=74, haunting=74, mediocre=74, laughable=74, nudity=73, bloody=73, slapstick=73, model=73, zero=73, ted=72, responsible=72, hurt=72, fly=72, wondering=72, eccentric=71, beast=71, thoroughly=71, ended=71, ill=71, inevitable=70, extra=70, steal=70, sorry=70, lacking=70, missed=70, ugly=70, mistake=69, hip=69, veteran=69, animal=68, chief=68, fill=68, suit=67, unexpected=67, tragedy=67, disappointment=67, warm=66, armageddon=66, cliched=66, positive=65, learned=65, genuinely=64, moved=64, aware=64, international=63, greater=63, freeman=63, elaborate=63, roughneck=62, unforgiving=62, unappetizing=62, stench=62, premium=62, psychological=62, danger=62, ravaging=62, flash=62, shlock=62, constipated=62, disability=62, woe=62, unworkable=62, lamentable=62, plaintive=62, ornery=62, patchy=62, disingenuous=62, unredeemable=62, remorseful=62, disrespect=62, terror=62, assimilating=62, satisfying=62, bitchiness=62, disappointed=62, derogatory=62, venomous=62, straying=62, stinking=62, woozy=62, conceited=62, ungodly=62, abysmally=62, soiled=62, scowl=62, grime=62, amicable=62, reconstructive=62, jobless=62, disadvantage=62, wearing=62, lugubrious=62, essentially=62, inexorable=62, painful=61, afraid=61, joy=61, threatening=61, drunken=60, suspenseful=60, psycho=60, passion=60, surely=59, suffering=59, warning=59, oddly=59, sole=59, nevertheless=59, climactic=59, lovely=59, bitter=58, wealthy=58, deadly=58, ape=58, patient=58, complicated=57, understanding=57, effectively=57, scare=57, unlikely=57, sudden=56, gag=56, extraordinary=56, quirky=56, beloved=56, 0=55, destroyed=55, frankly=55, chicken=55, unable=55, irritating=55, tragic=55, hype=55, unknown=54, nonetheless=54, promising=54, heroine=54, paid=53, obligatory=53, struggling=53, loser=53, inventive=52, erotic=52, absurd=52, provoking=52, remaining=52, hint=52, artistic=51, darkness=51, magical=51, beautifully=51, hopefully=51, notable=50, homage=50, inept=50, bleak=50, depressing=50, bother=49, cutting=49, flawed=49, obnoxious=49, cole=49, pleasant=49, instinct=49, brutal=49, trick=48, luckily=48, accomplished=48, deserve=48, disbelief=48, trite=48, fortunately=48, corny=47, intellectual=47, spoken=47, stylish=47, cruel=47, innocence=47, delight=47, expensive=47, mighty=47, favor=47, false=47, stereotypical=47, refreshing=47, training=46, honor=46, awkward=46, thrilling=46, legendary=46, gory=45, spots=45, virtual=45, consistently=45, base=45, deserved=45, wan=45, clueless=45, strangely=45, shut=45, endearing=45, expert=45, glory=45, energetic=44, handsome=44, insult=44, blind=44, crucial=44, everywhere=44, negative=44, received=43, bats=43, spirited=43, lifeless=43, fool=43, ironically=43, appropriately=42, confrontation=42, invisible=42, randy=42, legs=41, terrifying=41, shining=41, specifically=41, compare=41, crazed=41, ludicrous=41, ideal=41, charismatic=41, stunt=41, torn=41, diaz=41, eerie=41, vicious=41, campy=41, blank=41, reputation=41, searching=41, caring=41, flashy=41, inane=41, instantly=41, utter=41, flawless=40, nonsense=40, controlled=40, stab=40, wanting=40, foul=40, pat=40, pet=40, confusion=40, uninspired=40, experienced=40, affection=40, eager=39, melodramatic=39, absolute=39, detailed=39, separate=39, correct=39, craven=39, loyal=39, subtlety=39, superficial=39, enjoyment=39, sentimental=39, happiness=39, stranger=39, worthwhile=39, stupidity=38, paying=38, fell=38, altogether=38, advantage=38, honestly=38, sinister=38, manipulative=38, sleazy=38, credible=38, redeeming=38, ruin=38, excessive=38, protect=38, suspicious=38, crack=37, importance=37, cynical=37, shark=37, magnificent=37, sophisticated=37, showdown=37, regardless=37, harsh=37, corrupt=37, wreck=36, controversial=36, mild=36, proper=36, prepared=36, attempted=36, gem=36, changing=36, knight=36, ace=36, duke=36, devoted=36, macho=36, dozens=36, express=36, satan=35, wacky=35, struck=35, elderly=35, reluctant=35, proud=35, combat=35, uncomfortable=35, horrifying=35, nostalgia=35, evident=35, accurate=35, principal=34, uma=34, authentic=34, respective=34, insane=34, nearby=34, grim=34, shine=34, slight=34, busy=34, definite=34, unpleasant=34, firm=34, starred=34, rely=34, caliber=33, absent=33, acceptable=33, brutally=33, rough=33, unconvincing=33, guilt=33, fancy=33, astonishing=33, needless=33, sin=33, sly=33, composed=33, raging=32, lovable=32, nude=32, decidedly=32, aged=32, neat=32, neck=32, clumsy=32, triumph=32, comical=32, admire=32, popularity=32, unpredictable=32, mistaken=32, lively=32, depressed=32, dignity=32, marvelous=32, fable=32, raw=32, tiresome=32, bumbling=32, useless=32, immensely=32, torturer=31, officious=31, detrimental=31, mongrel=31, crackerjack=31, soured=31, unethical=31, mournfulness=31, asthmatic=31, upset=31, untraditional=31, cheating=31, undependable=31, contemptible=31, worn=31, irreplaceable=31, unopposed=31, befouled=31, gristly=31, softhearted=31, paucity=31, alleviated=31, malnutrition=31, crude=31, imponderable=31, secular=31, inconvenience=31, financial=31, singable=31, uncommercial=31, unmarried=31, indigestion=31, unfeasible=31, gloating=31, remarry=31, groveling=31, selfless=31, entranced=31, lecherous=31, trustworthiness=31, ruffian=31, heartbroken=31, interrogator=31, assured=31, placate=31, vertiginous=31, plausible=31, unhappy=31, surly=31, humbug=31, whiney=31, limitlessness=31, dispirited=31, insufficient=31, bungled=31, lovelorn=31, wounding=31, sold=31, irrefutable=31, convenient=31, xenophobic=31, rootless=31, preferable=31, jocular=31, pong=31, pneumonia=31, malaise=31, malevolence=31, detest=31, highbrow=31, cheapjack=31, reek=31, calm=31, egregious=31}
```

2) For every review, I create a vector that contains the number of occurrences of these 1500 words:

```
{exception=1, nicely=0, crappy=0, unconvincing=0, desperate=0, awful=0, wreck=0, satan=0, fumbling=0, ted=0, protected=0, poor=0, wasted=0, legs=0, understanding=0, absent=0, neat=0, inept=0, ashamed=0, unlikely=0, solid=0, inviting=0, excellent=0, younger=0, opulent=0, trashy=0, raw=0, inspired=1, compassionate=0, charismatic=1, apparent=0, 0=0, 1=0, bollocks=0, amusing=0, placate=0, poorly=0, bogus=0, notable=0, vertiginous=0, alienating=0, sentimental=0, plausible=0, catastrophic=0, salt=0, superlative=0, i=0, artistic=0, neck=0, weird=0, stunt=0, destroyed=0, corny=0, exciting=0, obvious=0, dogged=0, sweet=0, novel=0, malaise=0, acceptable=0, ace=0, eager=0, correct=0, moved=0, melancholic=0, jerking=0, woeful=0, good=4, fortunately=0, wish=0, deadly=0, wise=0, tiresome=0, roughneck=0, faint=0, nonexistent=0, add=0, murder=0, unopposed=0, pat=0, fantasy=0, obligatory=0, vicious=0, cruel=0, befouled=0, gristly=0, respect=0, gone=0, faux=0, gorgeous=0, softhearted=0, success=0, indignant=0, wacky=0, smashing=0, cynical=0, trust=0, raging=0, searching=0, wonderment=0, paucity=0, fugly=0, nowhere=0, disturbing=1, sorry=0, spirited=0, happiness=0, responsible=0, hard=0, mistake=0, redneck=0, malevolence=0, sexy=0, caliber=0, lucrative=0, better=0, woefully=0, crap=0, alleviated=0, truth=0, well=0, detest=0, creepy=0, taking=1, terrifying=0, wanting=0, resentful=0, invisible=0, changing=0, moral=0, tried=0, disappointment=0, loved=0, strangely=0, cameo=0, struck=0, hate=0, darkness=0, pet=0, gory=0, protecting=0, disrespect=0, tough=0, loving=0, malnutrition=0, unhappy=0, flawed=0, charming=0, erotic=0, spots=0, demonic=0, animated=0, crazy=0, mighty=0, homage=0, other=2, magnificent=0, highbrow=0, swell=0, crude=0, frankly=0, surly=0, amiss=0, melodramatic=0, wail=0, unforgiving=0, energetic=0, shark=0, famous=0, thoroughly=0, stupidity=0, question=0, honestly=0, worrying=0, spirit=0, imponderable=0, intellectual=0, cheap=0, humbug=0, sickly=0, torturer=0, officious=0, infamous=0, heartbreaking=0, kudos=0, duke=0, cop=0, cheapjack=0, honor=0, supernatural=0, rowdy=0, nasty=0, respectability=0, all=7, terror=0, read=0, plenty=0, less=0, alas=0, adventure=0, idyllic=0, secular=0, scowl=0, shining=0, evil=0, inconvenience=0, infatuated=0, badly=0, shame=0, overjoyed=0, torn=0, chicken=0, entertaining=0, rob=0, interfering=0, assimilating=0, bush=0, elderly=0, financial=0, dumb=0, combat=0, respective=0, trick=0, maddening=0, times=0, extra=0, busy=0, talented=1, detrimental=0, hapless=0, floor=0, idealized=0, wounded=0, guilt=0, stinky=0, chief=0, satisfying=0, despite=4, indignity=0, super=0, groan=0, caring=0, botch=0, fantastic=0, spoken=0, interested=1, bitchiness=0, lame=0, clumsy=0, meddling=0, accurate=0, pity=0, flawless=0, infuriating=0, decided=0, beautiful=0, whiney=0, generalized=0, limitlessness=0, botched=0, ape=0, lovable=0, welcome=0, devoted=0, reek=0, cheesy=0, wanted=1, pathetic=0, untamed=0, difference=0, must=1, deserved=0, flash=0, unoriginal=0, sophisticated=0, perfectly=0, goofy=0, nudity=0, dandy=0, killing=1, penniless=0, singable=0, giving=0, accident=0, excuse=0, drunken=0, humour=0, knight=0, disabled=0, mournful=0, insane=0, worried=0, unappetizing=0, stench=0, pointless=0, triumph=0, perplexed=0, silly=0, black=0, bliss=0, lacking=0, fortunate=0, entirely=0, boring=1, mongrel=0, calm=0, crackerjack=0, classic=1, charm=0, tragedy=0, absolute=0, contrived=0, feelings=0, battered=0, shapely=0, surely=0, becoming=0, wealthy=0, genuinely=0, sterling=0, unable=0, disappointed=0, dispirited=0, dying=0, paying=0, bias=0, sinister=0, brutally=0, basically=0, menacing=0, uncommercial=0, imagine=0, attractive=0, egregious=0, definite=0, superb=2, flashy=0, insufficient=0, uncomfortable=0, unmarried=0, surprising=0, worse=1, camp=0, improving=0, warm=0, guilty=0, embarrassing=0, everywhere=0, worst=0, despondent=0, derogatory=0, blind=0, color=0, hidden=0, indigestion=0, impossible=0, soured=0, showdown=0, complaining=0, non=0, disaster=0, mono=0, negative=0, chilling=0, venomous=0, outrageous=0, painful=0, pain=0, learned=0, wan=0, yes=0, effectively=0, appropriately=0, manipulative=0, stylish=0, genius=0, detailed=1, hype=0, delightful=0, motormouth=0, paid=0, short=0, stranger=0, attempted=0, horrifying=0, fancy=0, notorious=0, innocence=0, fab=0, happy=1, pleaser=0, overacting=0, nearby=0, unfeasible=0, grime=0, struggling=0, specifically=0, controversial=0, truly=0, greater=0, promising=0, okay=0, swoon=0, shlock=0, epic=0, horrid=0, saving=0, rely=0, apparently=0, bungled=0, excessive=0, completely=0, suit=0, bastard=0, damage=0, boss=0, masterful=0, bright=0, harsh=0, clueless=0, alien=0, smart=0, anti=0, unknown=0, diaz=0, bleak=0, premium=0, frivolous=0, gloating=0, low=0, droll=0, tragic=0, amusingly=0, older=0, confusing=0, protect=0, levity=0, mischief=0, comical=0, touching=0, inane=0, unfortunately=0, freeman=0, great=2, wrong=0, beautifully=0, disembodied=0, impressively=0, constipated=0, incredulous=0, choice=0, grim=0, small=3, crushing=0, shut=0, fiction=1, doom=0, disability=0, amicable=0, straying=0, hip=0, wondering=0, totally=0, potential=0, unethical=0, otherwise=0, kind=1, repugnant=0, lifeless=0, important=0, veteran=0, nerve=0, absolutely=0, affection=0, campy=0, psycho=0, wondrous=0, game=0, mommy=0, mournfulness=0, unexpected=0, crucial=0, rocky=0, principal=0, joy=0, patient=0, sad=0, phony=0, imitation=0, visually=0, depressing=0, nostalgia=0, deserve=0, revenge=0, nostalgic=0, clear=0, banner=0, armageddon=0, craven=0, slapstick=0, momma=0, shine=0, favor=0, neither=0, further=0, stupid=0, bad=0, luckily=0, depraved=0, fit=0, crack=0, unsatisfying=0, disenchanted=0, honest=0, giant=0, asthmatic=0, bumbling=0, killer=0, pseudo=0, sure=0, otherworldly=0, going=0, shock=0, loyal=0, mild=0, opportunity=1, reconstructive=0, downright=0, astonishing=0, trying=0, finer=0, stinking=0, hurt=0, average=0, compare=0, unwilling=0, admire=0, dead=0, soil=0, eyes=0, amuse=0, sudden=0, fool=0, unlike=0, popularity=1, brag=0, topping=0, bully=0, crummy=0, outstanding=0, keeping=0, sex=0, emotional=0, outraged=0, right=1, possible=0, battle=0, awesome=0, fly=0, glowing=0, meet=0, complicated=0, masterpiece=0, jobless=0, lovelorn=0, hollywood=0, beauty=0, scare=0, woe=0, needless=0, wounding=0, wretched=0, outdated=0, absurd=0, accomplished=0, unworkable=0, won=0, forgotten=0, useless=0, warning=0, scary=0, ed=0, needs=0, disadvantage=0, sumptuous=0, unpredictable=0, intriguing=0, suspicious=0, confrontation=0, inventive=0, horrific=0, never=0, phantom=0, oddly=0, blame=0, macho=0, nude=0, confusion=0, little=1, lucky=0, some=6, virtual=0, subtlety=0, blank=0, waiting=0, importance=0, uma=0, worthy=0, lamentable=0, training=0, mistaken=0, fox=0, content=0, legendary=0, woozy=0, trouble=0, conceited=0, sin=0, just=0, bloody=0, remarry=0, over=2, sole=0, sold=0, brilliant=0, crazed=0, abusive=0, go=0, wearing=0, false=0, obviously=0, sleazy=0, kept=0, grand=1, insomnia=0, disconcerting=0, endearing=0, decidedly=0, fiendish=0, atrocious=0, ludicrous=0, elaborate=0, very=6, expert=0, irrefutable=0, deplorable=0, provoking=0, delayed=0, sick=0, foul=0, superficial=0, easily=0, model=0, believable=0, autistic=0, fear=0, bonnie=0, disbelief=0, understated=0, letdown=0, plaintive=0, lively=0, crotchety=0, whiny=0, annoying=1, sly=0, ornery=0, upset=0, alive=0, unpleasant=0, majestic=0, abhorrent=0, lugubrious=0, ruthless=0, thinking=0, world=1, known=1, handicapped=0, composed=0, mangled=0, prejudice=0, hopefully=0, ability=0, together=0, delight=0, sadly=0, missed=0, positive=0, obnoxious=0, joking=0, off=0, joke=0, virtuoso=0, scummy=0, troublesome=0, complete=0, undeniable=0, forged=0, constant=0, instance=0, dreck=0, liked=0, second=0, confused=0, esteemed=0, fine=0, find=0, patchy=0, international=0, regardless=0, terrible=0, untraditional=0, ideal=0, pleasant=0, hamming=0, difficult=0, fill=0, cheating=0, plus=0, convenient=0, background=0, true=0, uninspired=0, malice=0, nonetheless=0, handsome=0, dozens=0, dangerous=0, groveling=0, best=2, decent=0, nonsense=0, eerie=0, troubled=0, loser=0, ok=0, make=1, rescue=0, experienced=0, reprehensible=0, highly=0, certainly=0, unfortunate=0, interesting=0, enthralled=0, cringing=0, intelligent=0, master=0, fright=0, extraordinary=0, selfless=0, due=0, howling=0, evident=0, authentic=0, essentially=0, heroine=0, worthwhile=0, undependable=0, sitting=0, psychological=0, credible=0, threatening=0, moralizing=0, bullshit=0, danger=0, somewhere=0, firm=0, extremely=0, speaking=0, starred=0, clever=0, reputable=0, horrible=0, drawn=0, recent=0, xenophobic=0, inevitable=0, horribly=0, unrealistic=0, underdog=0, miserable=0, wonderful=0, received=1, cracking=0, remaining=1, quality=0, glory=0, disastrous=0, propelling=0, disingenuous=0, animal=0, consistently=0, psychotic=0, sub=0, nevertheless=0, entranced=0, workmanlike=0, cute=0, ravaging=0, fell=0, unfunny=0, frightening=0, wonderfully=0, lecherous=0, apart=0, dirty=0, offensive=0, bother=0, righteous=0, necessary=0, thorough=0, beloved=0, reverend=0, controlled=0, face=0, definitely=0, stab=0, afraid=0, marvelous=0, bum=0, respected=0, randy=0, separate=0, suffering=0, instinct=0, buy=0, reputation=0, express=0, zero=0, amazing=0, trustworthiness=0, instantly=0, climactic=0, awkward=0, reluctant=0, passion=0, redeeming=0, ruin=0, formidable=0, admirable=0, please=0, troubling=0, punk=0, hint=0, know=0, eccentric=0, rough=0, proper=0, ruffian=0, cold=0, beast=0, cole=0, gag=0, bitter=0, contemptible=0, bats=0, shoddy=0, interest=0, damaging=0, hurting=0, missing=0, wonder=0, ungodly=0, gay=0, successful=0, lovely=0, brutal=0, corrupt=0, slight=0, winning=0, tumultuous=0, discernable=0, dramatic=0, damn=0, mediocre=0, superior=0, incredibly=0, imaginary=0, base=0, immensely=0, mom=0, whole=0, tingle=0, fable=0, schlock=0, none=0, fair=0, hell=0, quirky=0, humor=0, problem=0, lost=1, depressed=0, still=0, researcher=0, worn=0, lose=0, matt=0, ironically=0, props=0, fail=0, enjoyment=0, enjoyable=0, unredeemable=0, irritating=0, love=0, enjoy=0, gem=0, out=0, laughable=0, seeing=0, dark=0, witty=0, suspenseful=0, gusto=0, rootless=0, entrapment=0, aged=1, fascinating=0, suspect=0, nice=0, stink=0, opinion=0, lots=0, elegance=0, inexorable=0, altogether=0, emotion=0, elements=1, ended=0, cutting=0, fake=0, remorseful=0, squalor=0, upsetting=0, insult=0, magic=0, regrettably=0, villain=0, bizarre=0, perfect=0, utter=0, heartbroken=0, prepared=0, sound=0, preferable=0, healing=0, utterly=0, spite=0, abysmally=0, plain=0, criminal=0, incongruity=0, smelly=0, proud=0, like=5, ill=0, enamored=0, ugly=0, paranoia=0, messy=0, condemning=0, cliched=0, jocular=0, paranoid=0, sheltered=0, safe=0, interrogator=0, honored=0, thrilling=0, trite=0, regret=0, steal=0, irreplaceable=0, congratulations=0, stereotypical=0, pong=0, weep=0, engaging=0, seemingly=0, aware=0, filthy=0, soiled=0, pneumonia=0, ready=0, walking=0, disappointing=0, greatest=0, haunting=0, advantage=0, fault=0, really=0, nifty=0, expensive=0, magical=0, refreshing=0, assured=0, dignity=0, comic=0}
```

3) I'm using wekas naive bayes and k=10 cross fold evaluation:

```
Instances trainingSet = new Instances("Data", features.getAttributes(), 2000);         
trainingSet.setClassIndex(0); 


    // process every review, extract the ~1500 feature values and add them to the training-set
    rvw.getReviews().parallelStream().forEach((review) -> {
        Instance inst = new DenseInstance(features.getNumberOfFeatures()); // = 1501 features

        // get the word vector for this review
        HashMap<String,Integer> wordVector = stringToWordVectorChain.run(review.getReviewText());
        // set the sentiment class to positive or negative label
        features.setClass(inst, review.getPositiveOrNegative())); // sets the class attribute to positive or negative
        features.setFeatureValues(inst, wordVector); // for each feature it will do "setValue" on the instance

        trainingSet.add(inst);
    });


Classifier cModel = (Classifier) new NaiveBayes();
cModel.buildClassifier(trainingSet);

// Test the model
Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(trainingSet);
eTest.crossValidateModel(cModel, trainingSet, 10, new Random(1));

// print results
String strSummary = eTest.toSummaryString();
System.out.println(strSummary);
```

I tried experiment with different numbers of words (StringToWordVector uses ~1200), and different polarity thresholds, and 75% was the maximum accuracy my solution achieves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through Weka's `StringToWordVector` [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html), there seem to be a couple of implementation details different than yours. Here are the top two, based on how likely they are to be the reason for the performance difference you see, in my opinion:

- It seems that by default, the resulting vector is boolean (i.e. noting the existence of a word, rather than number of occurrences)
- If the class attribute is set before vectorizing the text, a separate dictionary is built for each class, then all dictionaries are merged.

While any of them (or other, more minor differences) could be the culprit, my bet is on the second point.

The built-in class allows setting and unsetting each of these options; you could try re-running the 80% version using `StringToWordVector` with the -C option to use number of occurences rather then a boolean value, and with -O, to use a single dictionary across both classes.

This should allow you to verify whether any of these is indeed the culprit.

EDIT: Regarding the first point, i.e. counting occurences vs. noting word existence (also called Bernoulli and multinomial models), there were several academic papers at the 90s which looked into the differences, e.g. [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~knigam/papers/multinomial-aaaiws98.pdf) and [here](https://ejournals.bc.edu/ojs/index.php/jtla/article/download/1668/1512). While usually the multinomial model works better, there are also opposite cases, depending on corpus and classification problem.

Comment: Thank you for your research! I couldn't notice any difference after changing counting occurences to word existence. Using separate dictionaries on the other hand did yield a 2-4% better result, depending on  the number of words contained in the vocabulary. I found another issue with my approach: I first thought, adding only words that have some polarity by checking the SentiWordNet would be a good thing. However, this actually lowers the accuracy! Another thing that helped, was using wekas AttributeSelection algorithm which selects the top attributes regarding redundancy etc. resulting in 83%

Comment: So my bet was almost correct :) Great to hear you were able to beat the buil-in baseline. Would be interesting to see if this holds to say a 10K or 100K dataset.